# Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN STATUS INTERNAL ERROR

Tags: algorithm, cudnn

I'm trying to create machinelearing in python 3.
but then i trying to compile my code i got this error in Cuda 10.0/cuDNN 7.5.0,
can some one help me with this?

RTX 2080

I'm on:
Keras (2.2.4)
tf-nightly-gpu (1.14.1.dev20190510)

> Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR

Code erorr:
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.`

Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 50, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, batch_size=n_batch)
```

> OOM when allocating tensor with shape[24946,32,48,48] and type float
>   on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc

Answer (score 8):

Using Tensorflow 2.0, CUDA 10.0 and CUDNN 7.5 the following worked for me:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
```

There are some other answers (such as the one here by venergiac) that use outdated Tensorflow 1.x syntax. If you are using the latest tensorflow you'll need to use the code I gave here.

If you get the following error:

```
Physical devices cannot be modified after being initialized
```

then the problem will be resolved by putting the `gpus = tf.config` ... lines directly below where you import tensorflow, i.e.

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
```

Comment: I put that line directly below where I import tensorflow but it doesn't work and I should restart the kernal?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible solutions.

## Problem on allocating GPU Memory

add the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.5)
config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.Session(config=config)
```

check also this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24496)

## Problem with your NVIDIA Driver

As posted [there](http://jugsi.blogspot.com/2019/05/configure-gpu-support-on-windows-10-for.html) you need to upgrade your NVIDIA Driver using ODE driver.

Please check [NVIDIA Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) for version of the driver

Comment: Hej, i got this error (OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:484 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[24946,32,48,48] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc) then i add your code.

Comment: did you test with smaller NN?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean with NN ?

Comment: But, my RTX 2080 works with (LSTM) But it does not work with (Conv2D)

Comment: OK it is similar to my case. I updated the driver to the latest version "430"

Comment: I'm on ubuntu server 16.04. not windows.

Comment: please add this info to the issue.......did you try to update the driver to the latest version? https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html

Comment: i'm on cuda 10.0 i have read tensorflow will not work with cuda 10.1. My driver version is 418.39 Ubuntu

Comment: me too! I'm on cuda 10.0 with 430 driver ... on linux >= 410.48 is required for CUDA but for CUDNN I do not know... please report the output of nvidia-smi

Comment: please refer to "One of the following supported CUDA versions and NVIDIA graphics driver:
NVIDIA graphics driver R410 or newer for CUDA 10.0 .. https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html" so it seems that you are OK...an it works on LSTM but not on Conv2D...my same case

Answer (score 0):

Roko's answer should work if you're using Tensorflow 2.0.

If you wanna set the exact amount of memory to limit(e.g. 1024MB or 2GB, etc.), there's another way to restrict your GPU memory usage.

Use this code:

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(gpus[0], [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
  except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
```

This code will limit your 1st GPU’s memory usage up to 1024MB. Just change the index of gpus and memory_limit as you want.